# Is there any difference between The Motorcycle Diaries Ocean press publication and film tie-in edition?

Tags: textual-history, diary

I recently bought the Harper Perennial Film tie-in edition of *The Motorcycle Diaries*. But after that I came to know that the original edition was published by Ocean press. So, is there any difference between the film tie-in edition and the original edition?